# Python numpy: Add elements of a numpy array of arrays to elements of another array of arrays initialized to at the specified positions

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Suppose we have a numpy array of numpy arrays of zeros as

```
arr1=np.zeros((len(Train),(L))
```

where `Train` is a (dataset) numpy array of arrays of integers of fixed length.
We also have another 1d numpy array, `positions` of length as `len(Train)`.

Now we wish to add elements of `Train` to `arr1` at the positions specified by `positions`.

One way is to use a for loop on the `Train` array as:

```
k=len(Train[0])
for i in range(len(Train)):
    arr1[i,int(positions[i]):int((positions[i]+k))]=Train[i,0:k])]
```

However, going over the entire `Train` set using the explicit for loop is slow and I would like to optimize it.

Comment: can you provide a full reproducible example by providing examples for `Train` and `L`/`positions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way by generating all the indexes you want to assign to. Setup:

```
import numpy as np

n = 12   # Number of training samples
l = 8    # Number of columns in the output array
k = 4    # Number of columns in the training samples

arr       = np.zeros((n, l), dtype=int)
train     = np.random.randint(10, size=(n, k))
positions = np.random.randint(l - k, size=n)
```

Random example data:

```
>>> train
array([[3, 4, 3, 2],
       [3, 6, 4, 1],
       [0, 7, 9, 6],
       [4, 0, 4, 8],
       [2, 2, 6, 2],
       [4, 5, 1, 7],
       [5, 4, 4, 4],
       [0, 8, 5, 3],
       [2, 9, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 7, 9],
       [8, 9, 4, 8],
       [8, 7, 6, 4]])
>>> positions
array([3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1])
```

Advanced indexing with broadcasting trickery:

```
rows = np.arange(n)[:, None]             # Shape (n, 1)
cols = np.arange(k) + positions[:, None] # Shape (n, k)
arr[rows, cols] = train
```

output:

```
>>> arr
array([[0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 6, 4, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 9, 6, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 5, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 8, 5, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 9, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 3, 7, 9, 0, 0],
       [0, 8, 9, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 8, 7, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0]])
```